# Forward clients to a specific ENI through ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I don't know if it's even possible to do so, but I will still ask. The thing is that I want to have (using ECS) one service **A** with tasks that do some job with the clients (create TCP connection, then form a group from multiple players and send to each player that they are formed in this group). Then I want this clients to make request to some specific task (some ENI with private IP, because I use awsvpc) from other service **B** behind an ALB (and then that task sends a response to those clients and starts working with them).

So my question is: "How can I forward multiple clients to the same specific ENI if that ENI is behind ALB?". Maybe in service's **A** tasks I should use AWS SDK to figure out the IPs of a service **B** tasks? But I still don't know how to reach that task by private IP. Is that even possible to "tell" ALB that I want to connect to some specific ENI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can configure the ALB to route to a specific IP. The listener on your ALB has routing rules that you can edit. Rules can be based on the domain name and path to which the HTTP request was sent.
Here is a detailed [Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html) on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks! I will test it, hope it will work fine for me.